# Been trying to install some stuff like pandas and numpy on Pycharm, but always get error

Tags: python, installation, pip, pycharm

So I've been trying to install numpy, pandas, matplotlib, Scikit Learn, scipy, and some other stuff required for my school work on Pycharm using the Python Packages tab, but keep getting this error:

```
Collecting numpy 
  Downloading numpy-1.24.3.tar.gz (10.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.9/10.9 MB 501.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [40 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "S:\Studying\Years\2nd\Semester_2\Introduction_to_Data_Science_&_Al\Lab_2\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_
hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "S:\Studying\Years\2nd\Semester_2\Introduction_to_Data_Science_&_Al\Lab_2\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_
hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "S:\Studying\Years\2nd\Semester_2\Introduction_to_Data_Science_&_Al\Lab_2\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_
hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
        File "S:\Studying\Years\2nd\Semester_2\Introduction_to_Data_Science_&_Al\Lab_2\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_
hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\Hoang Minh Tri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cv52nuhn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", l
ine 242, in <module>
          monkey.patch_all()
        File "C:\Users\Hoang Minh Tri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cv52nuhn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", lin
e 99, in patch_all
          patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
        File "C:\Users\Hoang Minh Tri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cv52nuhn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", lin
e 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
          patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
        File "C:\Users\Hoang Minh Tri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cv52nuhn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", lin
e 149, in patch_params
          mod = import_module(mod_name)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\Hoang Minh Tri\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cv52nuhn\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc
9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
          raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

When I do the same on the terminal, it seems to be already downloaded (perhaps from my previous attempts to do it in VSCode). And I install them just fine in VSCode. What can I do to make PyCharm installation work?

Comment: What this says is that the only version of the Visual C++ compiler you have is the 25-year-old antique, Visual C++ 6.0.  Modern Python requires a more modern compiler.  You can download a free Community Edition of Visual Studio.

Comment: ...or just install any other C compiler to avoid dealing with such monster as Visual Studio. AFAIC there was some way to install GCC on Windows, and Clang supports it natively (? not sure here). Google for instructions.